# Jquery UI Dialog Center

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a problem with centering a Jquery UI Dialog.

I'm bringing some images dynamically from FLICKR, when I click on my thumbnail, the image is positioned at the botton right of the page,
if I close the dialog and click the thumbnail again, then the Dialog opens in the correct centered position.

Why doesn't it appear at the right (centered) position on the first click?

Here is my JS

I have used this as my starting point http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated

```
$(function() {
    $( "#MYdialog" ).dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: 'middle',
        draggable: false,
        width: 'auto',
        center: true, 
        modal: true,
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade",             
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is happening because the image is not loaded when you open the dialog, try this:

```
var img = new Image()
img.src = "IMG_SRC"
$(img).load(function() {
  $("#content_img").html(img) //create a div with id="content_img" inside #MYdialog
  /*
    open dialog here
  */
});
```

Edit: forgot to use use load and call the dialog inside the callback

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix your markup to remove the extra comma:

```
show: "fade",         hide: "fade", 

show: "fade",         hide: "fade"
```

Full example:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#MYdialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
     resizable: false,
     position: 'middle',
     draggable: false,
     width: 'auto',
     center: true,
     modal: true,
     show: "fade",
     hide: "fade"
  });
});
```

Comment: i had so more after the hide fade thats why that i did not include here

Comment: hmm, one question then, if you remove BOTH the animations, does it work then?  Try to post ALL the stuff - you never know what might be missed.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered issues with the jQuery UI dialog as well, and worked around it the following way. Instead of declaring `center: true` (as it should work, but doesn't), I am using the following when I open the dialog:

```
$("#MYDialog").dialog("open")
    .dialog("moveToTop")
    .dialog('option', 'position', { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: "#wrapper" });
```

where `#wrapper` is an ID of a HTML element (for example a `div`) which is a frame around the screen you want to use to center the dialog (it can be invisible), e.g.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- your page content -->
</div>
```

Also, for other elements you can use [jquery.ui.position.js](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/source/browse/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.position.js?r=3700) to align them.
More examples of the position plugin can be found [here](http://jqueryui.com/position/), or check out the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/).